# duplicate mysql result to cycle it twice

Tags: php, mysql

I need to cycle a mysql result twice.
so I decided to duplicate its result into a new variable:

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$result_copy = $result;
```

Then I cycle my `$result` and print the data.
But when I try to cycle `$result_copy` the `while` won't work.
I can solve the problem by using `mysql_data_seek($result_copy, 0)` but I want to understand why the copy won't start from [0].
Thanks in advance!
-----------------------
I'm posting a longer version of my code:

```
$query = [...];
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
$result_copy = $result;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   [...] // this outputs the data
}
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_copy)) {
    [...] // No data are shown here. Pointer is at the end of $result_copy
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are removed in PHP 7. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead. 
And please, show us your code

Comment: All my new projects use PDO. ATM I'm working on an old job, not mine, and changing 1M lines of code into PDO is just not feasible. Updating with code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data rows are retrieved by the *mysql_fetch_array($result)* statement.
If you copy *$result* you simply are copying the handle (resource id), not the data.

So, you either repeat the *while* loop, or repeat the action you take wihin the *while* loop:

```
<?php

$query = [...];
$result = mysql_query($query, $db);
// $result_copy = $result;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // We got a row here ...
   foreach($row as key => $value) 
       [...] // Do this ...
       [...] // Do that again ...
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

because your `$result` stored the `Resource id`

not `all` the record thats why

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you have to use a `clone` for create $result_copy.
Reason (from PHP5 manual):

> As of PHP5, an object variable doesn't contain the object itself as value anymore. It only contains an object identifier which allows object accessors to find the actual object. When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object.

So this is reason why is pointer on last position.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because `mysql_query()` returns an internal data structure called `resource` which holds its own pointer to currently processed row. When you do `$result_copy = $result;` you're not making a copy, you're just assign its pointer to another variable.

Using `mysql_data_seek($result, 0)` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is based on the [docs of mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

> Returns an array that corresponds to the fetched row and moves the
>   **internal data pointer ahead**.